# PHP Combine Associative Arrays If Specific Key Matches

Tags: php, arrays

UPDATED QUESTION

What if both arrays contain multiple entries that you must iterate over to compare for the merge? I have attempted this with a nested `foreach` like so:

```
foreach ($vehicleArr as $v) {
  foreach ($specialArr as $s) {
    if ($v['vehicle'] === $s['vehicle']) {
      $freshArr[] = array_merge($v, $s);
    } else {
      $freshArr[] = $v;
    }
  }
}
```

This creates a massive memory leak and kills the script.

ORIGINAL QUESTION

I am working to combine 2 different arrays based on the comparison of a key if the values match, otherwise the combine does not occur.

Here is an example of each array to begin with:

```
Vehicle Array
(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van
  [stockno] => 153721
  [msrp] => 32195
  [price] => 32195
  [payment] => 359
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Van
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => Transit 250
  [trim] => Cargo Van
),(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford F150 XLT
  [stockno] => 153723
  [msrp] => 36195
  [price] => 36195
  [payment] => 429
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Truck
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => F150
  [trim] => XLT
```

)

```
Special Array
(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van
  [store] => Baxter Ford
  [offertype] => $ Off MSRP
  [offervalue] => Up to $10,000
  [disclaimer] => *Valid on in-stock models. Based on stock #161621. Tax, title and license extra. With approved credit. Includes hail sale savings. See dealer for details. Offer expires 8\/1\/16.
  [expires] => 8/1/16
)
```

The goal is to combine on Vehicle Array[vehicle] and Special Array[vehicle] to create an array like this:

```
Combined Array
(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van
  [stockno] => 153721
  [msrp] => 32195
  [price] => 32195
  [payment] => 359
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Van
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => Transit 250
  [trim] => Cargo Van
  [store] => Baxter Ford
  [offertype] => $ Off MSRP
  [offervalue] => Up to $10,000
  [disclaimer] => *Valid on in-stock models. Based on stock #161621. Tax, title and license extra. With approved credit. Includes hail sale savings. See dealer for details. Offer expires 8\/1\/16.
  [expires] => 8/1/16
),(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford F150 XLT
  [stockno] => 153723
  [msrp] => 36195
  [price] => 36195
  [payment] => 429
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Truck
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => F150
  [trim] => XLT
)
```

This seems extremely simple, but I seem to missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: array_merge() isn't good enough?

Comment: `foreach ($arrayA as &$row) { if ($row['vehicle'] === $special['vehicle']) { $row = array_merge($row, $special); } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting to only merge the special array onto items in your vehicle array with the same vehicle. You just need to check the vehicle key as you go, and only merge items where they key matches. There are a few ways to do that. Here is one using `array_map`.

```
$combined = array_map(function($v) use ($special_array) {
    if ($v['vehicle'] == $special_array['vehicle']) {
        return array_merge($v, $special_array);
    }
    return $v;
}, $vehicle_array);
```

I have to say, though, from my experience working with vehicle data, it seems pretty likely that the data in the `vehicle` key may not match in some cases where it really is the same type of vehicle due to slight differences that may be in the text there. If there's any way you could use year, make, model, trim to match with your special array it would probably work more consistently. (Unless `vehicle` is already made *from* year, make, model, trim, in which case, never mind.)

Comment: For some reason, I find `foreach($vehicles as $k=>$v){
 if($v['vehicle'] == $special_array['vehicle']){
  $vehicles[$k] = array_merge($vehicles[$k], $special_array['vehicle']);
  break;
 }
}` easier to look and understand what's going on. Are there any practical differences or just tomayto / tomahto?

Comment: @FirstOne The only real difference is that `array_map` creates a new array while `foreach` _in that way_ modifies the existing array. Of course, you could create a new array with `foreach` just as easily. As far as a difference in performance, I don't know exactly, but it should be minimal. Other than that it's just a style preference IMO.

Comment: Yeah, most of the time it's just about style preference really. Thanks for the reply ;)  cya

Comment: What if both arrays contain multiple entries that you must iterate over to compare for the merge?`foreach ($vehicleArr as $v) {
  foreach ($specialArr as $s) {
    if ($v['vehicle'] === $s['vehicle']) {
      $freshArr[] = array_merge($v, $s);
    } else {
      $freshArr[] = $v;
    }
  }
}`
This creates a massive memory leak and kills the script.